# SQL Server : how to enforce Primary Key cannot exist as Primary Key in another table constraint - trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, primary-key

I have a table `LotTable` that has a `PK= LotID, Name, rate`.

I have another table `LotTranslate` that has a `PK=TranslateLotID` and `FK=MasterLotID`

Before insert into `LotTable` I need to make sure enforce the `PK` inserted is NOT already the PK in `LotTranslate`.

My question is do I do a trigger instead of insert or Delete it after? What is the most clean way, speedy way to check this other table and stop the insert in `LotTable` if the PK is found there in `LotTranslate`?

My direction I am not sure if this is the right SQL Server way...

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_LotsInsert ON LotTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO dbo.LotTable
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE INSERTED.LotID not in (select TranslateLotID from LotTranslate)
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend using a trigger to enforce this.

What you are describing is actually inheritance, where different objects share a base type. In this case, you have the base concept of a `Lot` (called the *supertype*), and two mutually exclusive *subtypes*, `LotTable` and `LotTranslate`. (And for the record, I think it unfortunate that your database has a table with the name `Table` in it, unless it actually deals with some kind of tables that aren't database objects).

There is a reasonably well-established database design pattern to deal with subtypes and supertypes: creating a parent table that is used as the "base object" in the inheritance pattern, and making the subtype tables all have an FK relationship to it. To additionally enforce the mutual exclusivity, you can add a `Type` column to all the tables and involve it in the foreign key.

Then, your base table participates with the two tables in a 1-to-zero-or-one relationship. The most important concept to get here is that the `LotID` is always the same in all the tables and you do not create separate surrogate keys for any table: the base/supertype table contains the same values that are in the child/subtype tables.

Before I show you how to accomplish this, let me mention that in this case it's possible your two tables should really be combined into one, with a simple `Type` column indicating which it is which would of course prevent a single Lot from being two types at once. I'm assuming, however, that your two tables have enough columns different between them that it would be a big waste of `NULL` values to do so (if there are only a few columns different, it may be better to just combine them).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LotBase (
   LotID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_LotBase PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   LotTypeID tinyint NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT FK_LotBase_LotTypeID FOREIGN KEY
      REFERENCES dbo.LotType (LotTypeID),
-- A unique constraint needed for FK purposes
   CONSTRAINT UQ_LotBase_LotID_LotTypeID
      UNIQUE (LotID, LotTypeID)
);

-- Include script here to create a LotType table and populate it with two rows
--    1 = `Standard Lot` and 2 = `TranslateLot`

INSERT dbo.LotBase (LotID, LotTypeID)
SELECT LotID, 1
FROM dbo.LotTable;

INSERT dbo.LotBase (LotID, LotTypeID)
SELECT TranslateLotID, 2
FROM dbo.LotTranslate;

ALTER TABLE dbo.LotTable ADD LotTypeID tinyint NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT DF_LotTable_LotTypeID DEFAULT (1);

ALTER TABLE dbo.LotTranslate ADD LotTypeID tinyint NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT DF_LotTranslate_LotTypeID DEFAULT (2);

ALTER TABLE dbo.LotTable ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LotTable_LotBase
   FOREIGN KEY (LotID, LotTypeID)
   REFERENCES dbo.LotBase (LotID, LotTypeID);

ALTER TABLE dbo.LotTable ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LotTable_LotBase
   FOREIGN KEY (LotID, LotTypeID)
   REFERENCES dbo.LotBase (LotID, LotTypeID);
```

Note that you might want to do the work to get the new `LotTypeID` columns in the child tables to be situated immediately after the `LotID` columns, but it is up to you--just be careful because it will require table recreation and you can harm your database if you are not knowledgeable and careful (take backups first!).

One huge benefit of this pattern to not miss is that anywhere in your database you want an FK to a `Lot`, you can choose to either use one of the child tables or to use the parent table. This constrains your other tables to allow either both or just one of the subtypes. Another benefit to not miss is that you can put common columns between the two tables into the parent table instead of repeated in the children. Finally, you can create a view for each child that exposes the combined parent + child columns just like the original child table.

Finally, if you persist in going on with the trigger method, you don't have to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger. You can just `ROLLBACK` any transaction that isn't appropriate:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_LotTable_I ON dbo.LotTable FOR INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM
      Inserted I
      INNER JOIN dbo.LotTranslate LT
         ON I.LotID = LT.TranslateLotID
) ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

That's a far better way to handle it (for one thing, you won't have to modify it every time you add a column to your `LotTable` table. Also, I would recommend that you learn to use (and then consistently use) `JOIN` syntax instead of the `IN` syntax you showed. While there is some controversy over this recommendation I'm making, in my experience people who use `IN` instead of `JOIN`s miss some key conceptual learning that goes on in the process of figuring out how to make them into `JOIN`s. There are other practical benefits such as the fact that nested `IN` queries get abominably hard to understand and maintain, while adding 5 more `JOIN`s doesn't really make a query much harder to understand when formatted well.

Comment: Thanks ErikE - I cannot implement the bigger solution this table actually does not have TABLE in the name, the lotTranslate is a wee as in really small table patch to manage some routing of phone numbers that caused this mess, so your trigger works like a charm.  I understand IN but the join is fine for this, and all of these tables have been redesigned so this s a temp patch and your trigger is perfect for the few months it will protect from insert mistakes.